# fetch inside fetch error setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem solving this react.js

```
loadFromServer(pageSize) {

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/employees')
        .then(response => {
            return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/employees',
            {
                headers: new Headers({
                'Accept': 'application/schema+json'
              })
            }).then(schema => {
                this.scheme =  schema;
                return response.json();
            }   
            )

       })
        .then(response =>             
            this.setState(
                {
                employees: response._embedded.employees,
                attributes: Object.keys(this.scheme.json().properties),
                pageSize: pageSize,
                links: response._links}                      
            )
        );          
    }
```

at this part

```
attributes: Object.keys(this.scheme.json().properties),
```

always return (in promise) `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.`

If I put `console.log(this.scheme.json())` I can see the Promise but, why inside `setState` I get null object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- The main one is that `this.schema.json()` returns a promise (as you know from your `console.log`). Promises don't have a `properties` property, so you're passing `undefined` to `Object.keys`, which then gives you that error.
- You're also not checking for errors from `fetch`, in two different ways: You're not checking `.ok` (which is such a common error [I've posted about it on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)), and you're not checking for promise rejection.

You're also doing some unnecessary promise nesting and could be overlapping your `fetch` calls more.

First, since it seems you often fetch JSON, I'd suggest giving yourself a utility function for it:

```
function fetchJSON(...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('HTTP error ' + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

Notice the `.ok` check.

Then, also in the "break the problem into smaller pieces" category, I'd have a `fetchSchema` function:

```
function fetchSchema(url) {
    return fetchJSON(url, {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/schema+json'
        })
    });
}
```

Then, `loadFromServer` can use `Promise.all` and destructuring to run the operations in parallel:

```
// (I assume this is in a `class` or object initializer, as it doesn't have `function` in front of it)
loadFromServer(pageSize) {
    Promise.all(
        fetchJSON('http://localhost:8080/api/employees'),
        fetchSchema('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/employees')
    )
    .then(([empResponse, schema]) => {
        this.schema = schema;
        this.setState({
            employees: empResponse._embedded.employees,
            attributes: Object.keys(schema.properties),
            pageSize: pageSize,
            links: empResponse._links
        })
    )
    .catch(error => {
        // Do something with the error
    });
}
```

Note the `.catch`, since you're not returning the promise from `loadFromServer`. (If you want to buck errors up the chain, add `return` in front of `Promise.all` and move the `.catch` to calling code.)

---

Side note: Your code used

```
this.scheme =  schema;
```

Note that the property on the left is `scheme` (with a final `e`) but the variable is `schema` (with a final `a`). I think you meant `schema` and so I've included that change in the above, but if the property is really supposed to be `this.scheme`, you'll want to adjust that. Or if you don't need that property for anything other than the code in `loadFromServer`, remove that line entirely.

Comment: Why do we need `this.schema = schema;` any more? :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I assume this is a method and that having that property is important. Naturally, if the OP doesn't need that property, they should remove that.

Comment: I agree. But I am assuming OP stored it to `this` to access it later, but that fundamental was wrong which the OP realised from the error message. So, it is probably no more needed.. Anyway it is OP's call. I just tried to make a note here.

Comment: yes.. its important using `catch`error if something happen while fetching..thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `Promise.all` to run the two requests in parrallel and then retrieve the two responses (by the way `response.json()` returns a `Promise`, that's why you have an error in your code) :

```
loadFromServer(pageSize) {
    Promise.all([
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/employees')
        .then(response => {
           if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
           return response.json();
        ),
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/employees')
        .then(response => {
           if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
           return response.json();
        ),
    ]).then(responses => {
        this.setState({
          employees: responses[0]._embedded.employees,
          attributes: Object.keys(responses[1].properties),
          pageSize: pageSize,
          links: responses[0]._links
        })
    }).catch(error => {...})        
}
```

Comment: yups .. using promise.all is elegant way to handle pararel fetching...thank you so much.

Comment: It also ignores errors from `fetch`, which will eventually turn into "Unhandled promise rejection"s.

Comment: yep btw I am not a big fan of `fetch` api, I prefer using `axios` which is in my opinion easier to use

Answer (score 1):

Response `json()` method in Fetch API [returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). For this reason `fetch` requests should be consistently chained with `.then(response => response.json())` to get a plain object.

Flattening promises may result in more reliable control flow. Since responses from both requests are used, this would require to either nest `then` callbacks or passing another response through `then` chain. `async` may be useful because it conveniently solves flattening problem:

```
async loadFromServer(pageSize) {
    const employeesResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/employees', {
      headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/schema+json' })
    });
     const employees = await employeesResponse.json();

    const schemeResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/employees', {
      headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/schema+json' })
    });
    const scheme = await schemeResponse.json();

    this.setState({
        employees: employees._embedded.employees,
        attributes: Object.keys(scheme.properties),
        pageSize: pageSize,
        links: response._links
    });
}
```

Since requests don't depend on each other, they could be performed in parallel with `Promise.all`.

```
async loadFromServer(pageSize) {
    const employeesPromise = fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/employees', {
      headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/schema+json' })
    })
    .then(res => res.json());

    const schemePromise = fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/employees', {
      headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/schema+json' })
    })
    .then(res => res.json());

    const [employees, scheme] = await Promise.all([employeesPromise, schemePromise]);

    this.setState({
        employees: employees._embedded.employees,
        attributes: Object.keys(scheme.properties),
        pageSize: pageSize,
        links: response._links
    });
}
```

Comment: Then how do I get response second fetch --> schema to put in setState()?

Comment: With ES6 this this usually involves either nested `then`, or passing responses through `then`s with spread/destructuring syntax, or assigning them to temp variables in parent scope. This becomes much simpler with `async` Updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
loadFromServer(pageSize) {
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/employees')
    .then(response => {
      return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/profile/employees', {
        headers: new Headers({
          'Accept': 'application/schema+json'
        })
      }).then(schema => {
        schema.json().then(data => {
          this.scheme = data
        })
      });
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(response =>
      this.setState({
        employees: response._embedded.employees,
        attributes: Object.keys(this.scheme.properties),
        pageSize: pageSize,
        links: response._links
      })
    );
}
```